# Resizing the canvas of JIT graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

How do I resize the canvas of th JIT Graph after it's been once drawn?
JIT Force Directed Graph [is described here](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html)

I've tried smt like the following (using jQuery):

```
function resizeCanvas(size) {
var e$ = $('#visualizerView, #visualizerContainer');

e$.animate(
    {height: "+=" + size + "px"},
    500
);

//TODO make it work?
//$('#visualizerView').empty();
//var pos = fdGraph.canvas.getPos(true);
//alert(pos.x+" "+pos.y)
//fdGraph.canvas.translate(0, -50);
//fdGraph.canvas
//initGraph(graph);
```

}

But I the best thing I can do is to stretch the container DIV - not the canvas itself. When I stretch the canvas the aspect ratio gets wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Canvas pixel buffer width and height are coordinated independently from the documentation presentation (style) width and height.

[Canvas width and height in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5)

Comment: I don't know why, but I simply can't properly resize a JIT Graph. Circles turn into ovals. Perhaps you could provide a jQuery 2-liner showing how to resize `<canvas>`

Comment: You must be messing up your aspect ration.