# viewport problem using javascript PDF.js viewport

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

i'm using pdf.js and all worked fine until yesterday.
Now i get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PDFPageProxy.getViewport is called with obsolete arguments.
    at PDFPageProxy.getViewport (api.js:964)
```

I have set a const for the viewport `const viewport = page.getViewport(scale);`

```
  /**
   * @param {GetViewportParameters} params - Viewport parameters.
   * @returns {PageViewport} Contains 'width' and 'height' properties
   *   along with transforms required for rendering.
   */
  getViewport({ scale, rotation = this.rotate, dontFlip = false, } = {}) {
    if ((typeof PDFJSDev !== 'undefined' && PDFJSDev.test('GENERIC')) &&
        (arguments.length > 1 || typeof arguments[0] === 'number')) {
      throw new Error(
        'PDFPageProxy.getViewport is called with obsolete arguments.');
    }
    return new PageViewport({
      viewBox: this.view,
      scale,
      rotation,
      dontFlip,
    });
  }
```

i don't know what's wrong.
p.s. i'm not a js master.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd guess you are passing a number to that method in `scale` argument? Like

```
page.getViewport(1) // this worked before in pre 2.1 versions
```

It should be an object: try

```
page.getViewport({scale:1}) // since 2.1 onward
```

instead. Or in your particular case:

```
page.getViewport({scale:scale})
```

---

Version number this (breaking) change occurred taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990484/540955) that even points to [relevant PR](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/10369).