# Getting the height of a canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've created a simple canvas element

```
<canvas style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

when I try to get the height, however in javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(config.elementId);
console.log(canvas.height); //150
console.log(canvas.width); //300

console.log(canvas.style.height); //100%
console.log(canvas.style.width); //100%
```

If I inspect the element in chrome's debugger, and actually mouse over the element, chrome is reporting the element size as

```
1627x925px
```

How on earth do I get to the `1627x925px` measurements in js?

Comment: See the last bit of the accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alex says, **you can use the `getComputedStyle` function  to get the current size** of the canvas.

**But...** to make the canvas full screen width and height always, meaning even when the browser is resized, you need to run your draw loop within a function that resizes the canvas to the `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`.

Once you do that, you can use the normal `canvas.height` and `canvas.width` functions to get properly the canvas size:

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        /* Your drawings need to be inside this function
         * to avoid canvas to be cleared. */
        drawStuff(); 
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
        console.log(canvas.height); //925
        console.log(canvas.width); //1627
        // do your drawing stuff here
    }
})();
```

**Plus:** Use this CSS hacks to make the canvas full size without problems:

```
/* remove the top and left whitespace */
* { margin:0; padding:0; } 

/* just to be sure these are full screen*/
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }

/* To remove the scrollbar */
canvas { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can spy on the computed styles!

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas).height
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas).width
```

Comment: `getComputedStyle(canvas).height` suffices.