# Resize the canvas with fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

The application lets user save the designs and post it so other users can view it later.

The original canvas saved with the proportions of width=700 and height=600. But when displaying the canvas, I want to resize the canvas to fit into dimensions of (350,300). half of the original. But if I directly apply those dimensions and load width setWidth() and setHeight() it loads with original proportions.

All I want is to display the canvas with new dimensions.

Comment: This is most-definitely NOT a duplicate, as this involves fabric.js

Comment: Even though that was the case, the solution was more of a generic one. The solution didn't involve anything specific to fabricJS . So I won't argue.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

Previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5).

I'm not sure what you've been trying, but

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
canvas.width  = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
```

should work fine.

Comment: This will not work on a fabric.Canvas

Answer (score 108):

If you are using the library fabric.js, that's not enough.

Considering that 'canvas' is the fabric.js instance object, you should do this to avoid distorsion artifacts:

```
canvas.setWidth( <desired width> );
canvas.setHeight( <desired height> );
canvas.calcOffset();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Correct, if you are using fabric you need to do this.