# lineTo on HTML 5 canvas not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to learn canvas.

I was trying to draw some lines using moveTo() and lineTo() on canvas.

The co-ordinates I give and the point rendered over canvas are not matching

I have taken a canvas of size 500px X 500px

for (0,0) it is coming fine.

for all other points it is not matching the co-ordinates

for (300, 150) it is painting at (500,500).

I'm not getting why this is happening because if I set my canvas size t0 300px X 150px it is painting correctly

here is my js

```
    var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(100, 100);
    context.lineTo(100, 100);
    context.lineTo(200, 100);
    context.lineTo(300, 150);
    context.stroke();
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/nLUEX/)

Can any one please tell me where I'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

set the height and width of the canvas element directly:
`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"> </canvas>`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLUEX/2/

Comment: it didn't work. setting the style from css and inline styling are the same. except that inline style will be given more precedence.

Comment: hmmm...don't think that's exactly true: http://jsfiddle.net/9RJXQ/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5

Comment: but that didn't work for me, you can do the changes in js fiddle check. anyways I will check again.