# Save HTML5 Canvas with upscaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am developing a image editor that has text on it using HTML5 canvas. The canvas I am using has the width and the height of 500 pixels because of the less room to place it on the web page. However I need to save the canvas data as an image in a bigger scale like 1000 x 1000 pixels. How can I achieve this? I search for similar issue on the web but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you will need to set the `width` and `height` attributes on the canvas to `1000` and `1000`. This represents the native size of the canvas. Then you can scale down the canvas using CSS to get it to fit on your page.

Example HTML:

```
<canvas id="theCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Example CSS:

```
theCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

For more information about native vs scaled canvas sizing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939066/2234742).