# Placing an image on a canvas JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, drawimage

I have the following in `html`:

```
<img id="MarkingImage"></img>                
<canvas id="MarkingCanvas"></canvas>
```

And on `css`:

```
#MarkingCanvas { width: 100%; background-color: #7986CB; height: 96%; }
#MarkingImage { position: absolute; }
```

And on `js`:

```
function LoadImage()
{
   var markingImage = new Image();

   markingImage.addEventListener('load', function() 
   {
       m_imageWidth = this.naturalWidth;
       m_imageHeight = this.naturalHeight;

       m_markingCanvasContext.drawImage(markingImage, 0, 0, m_imageWidth,  m_imageHeight);
   });
   markingImage.src = 'PICT0001.JPG';
}
```

The thing is that this output stretches the image and it's quality gets really poor (see attached "Original" and "Result").
[image: Original Image]

[image: Result Image]

When I debug, I can see that the sizes if my canvas are:

`width - 1410`
`height - 775`

The sizes if my image are:

`width - 551`
`height - 335`

So my question is: why isn't the image placed in it's original size? I mean, there's enough space on the canvas. Also, why does the image gets stretched, and as a result gets in pretty low quality. Appears like it stretches beyond the size of the canvas.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5). You should define the canvas' height and width properties instead of using css.

Comment: Ok, that helped thanks! But then the dimensions are hard-coded, and if I open the website on a, laptop, for example, then the canvas is too big, I wanted the size to be determined automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: Also see [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) (and its equivalents, mozImageSmoothingEnabled & webkitImageSmoothingEnabled). This can sometimes affect image quality, but isn't supported on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the canvas width and height dynamically according to the browser window's width and height. also, there is no need to use the image's `naturalWidth / naturalHeight`.

```js
var m_markingCanvas = document.getElementById('MarkingCanvas');
var m_markingCanvasContext = m_markingCanvas.getContext('2d');

// setting canvas width and height dynamically
m_markingCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
m_markingCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function LoadImage() {
    var markingImage = new Image();
    markingImage.addEventListener('load', function() {
        m_markingCanvasContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    });
    markingImage.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Wpy.jpg';
}
LoadImage();
```

```html
<canvas id="MarkingCanvas"></canvas>
```