# The Text on The Canvas Looks Pretty Blurry

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

There is no blur when I run the code in the compilers on the internet, but it seems quite blurry when I run it on my project. What could be the reason for this? Photos and codes are below.

.ts code

```
    public DrawTheTree() {
    var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("tree_canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        context.beginPath();
        context.font = "16px Comic Sans MS";
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText("Animals", 150, 15);
        context.closePath();    
    }
```

.html code

```
<canvas id="tree_canvas" class="tree_canvas_class"></canvas>
```

.css code

```
.tree_canvas_class {
background-color: darkblue;
width: 936px;
height: 435px;
}
```

BlurryPhoto:https://www.dropbox.com/s/mle8vepnyesapip/Capture.JPG?dl=0
DesiredPhoto: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0fwn46ibrgascy/ss.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the wordcloud in the canvas is blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010056/why-the-wordcloud-in-the-canvas-is-blurry)

Comment: How can I do that in ts file?

Comment: Add to the canvas.  `canvas.width = 936; canvas.height = 435;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix blurry text in my HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661339/how-do-i-fix-blurry-text-in-my-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the reason for this?

That's how canvas works. [It's a raster image, not a vector](https://designshack.net/articles/layouts/vector-vs-raster-what-do-i-use/).

You create a text using 16px font (`context.font = "16px Comic Sans MS"`) and then enlarge it by using CSS (`width: 936px; height: 435px;`).

There are a few possible solutions to make the text non-blurry.

- Do not use canvas.
- Do not resize canvas.

Comment: Will I first create the text, then expand the canvas?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I have to use canvas unfortunately.

Comment: That's why the second option says, "do not resize [it]".

Comment: To clarify the "do not resize", if you want a large canvas don't scale it with CSS, simply create a bigger canvas to begin with and fill it with a larger font size.

Comment: I have to do that too, boss.

Comment: Then you cannot expect it to not be blurry. HTML5 is not a crime investigation TV show. Images cannot be enlarged without loss of quality or guessing.its content.

Comment: It's a very weird situation where you *have* to use a css-scaled canvas to display this text... If that's the case, I'm afraid I don't believe you can make the text any clearer.

Comment: Friends, the size of my canvas has to be 936px-435px and I want to print text on this canvas. This text does not have to be 16 px, of course. However, this text should be readable and clear on canvas. That's all I want.

Comment: Then create the canvas `936px` by `435px` from the start, do not resize it via CSS.

Comment: Okay, now I see. Thank you for your contribution