# Resizing canvas size gives advantage to larger screens. Not sure how to keep the functionality while making it fair

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to learn javascript by making a game where you click on a canvas to move a circle and you have to dodge multiple other circles coming in your direction. I am close to the final result but I just realized that the larger your screen is, the **easier** it is for you to play.

The reason is that the enemies spawn at the edges of the canvas, so if the canvas is bigger, you have more time to react to them since their speed doesn't change. The game is supposedly refreshing around 60fps and each time it resizes the canvas depending on if you change your window size. The only thing I can think of is increasing the speed of enemies with the size increase but I don't know if there's any other way to go about this. Maybe I could increase the size of the of the player and the enemies to accommodate the change in window size but I don't know which is better or how to make sure I am consistent with the ratio increase.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time

Here's my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/r2f6eb89/2/
It doesn't actually run on this site so it's just a reference for my logic.

Here are the resizing functions:

```
/*
function setCanvasSize() {
  //c.width = window.innerWidth-100;
 //c.height = window.innerHeight-100;

if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
c.width = window.innerWidth - 150;
c.height = window.innerWidth - 150;
} else {
   c.width = window.innerHeight - 150;
   c.height = window.innerHeight - 150;
}
}
*/
 function setCanvasSize() {
 c.width = 600;
 c.height = 600;
}
```

Comment: there's vw and vh to express screen percentages. So if you use those instead of pixels, everything should scale.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually **two kinds** of "width" and "height" property. One is the width and height you can **actually** see in your website, that is, the one you can change by the property on your html file element. The other one is the width and height you set in the javascript file, for **setting the coordinate** you use to print image or draw in the canvas.

Example for **first type** of the width/height property:

```
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Example for **second type** of the width/height property:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");

canvas.width=500;
canvas.height=200;
```

It seems like you are changing the **second type** of the width/height property each refresh. If that's not what you want, try modifying the **first type** of width/height. It seems like a simpler solution to your question. To modify the first type of property, the CSS property in javascript, here's the code:

```
canvas.style.width="500px";
canvas.style.height="200px";
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Supercool. I don't know if I am wrong. This is a discuss that's similar to what I'm trying to say: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5 I didn't verify it with web informations before, so I might get wrong. But I did test before. And I thought the op is just trying to "resize the canvas" while keeping the game fair because of the window size's changing: ```The game is supposedly refreshing around 60fps and each time it resizes the canvas depending on if you change your window size. ```

Comment: Hey @Acc-lab I understand I was wrong about your answer.but your answer doesn't actually answer the op's question. That's why I added a comment.

Comment: @Supercool. I think if they use ```canvas.style.width``` or ```canvas.style.height``` into ```c.style.width = window.innerWidth - 150; c.style.height = window.innerWidth - 150;``` the canvas can resize perfectly while the game's function won't broke(since if the screen's size decrease, the speed will decrease and they'll scale, too). The host did not use this method, and they use a method instead, that is to resize the canvas unpropotionally. This way, the enemy can really spawn at the edge while the speed don't decrease, everything won't scale, and makes the game's hardness broke.

Comment: @Supercool. Edit: you shouldn't use ```c.style.width``` or ```c.style.height``` individually at the same time if you want it to be propotional though.