# Why would my canvas scale itself in converting html to DOM calls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, canvas

In refactoring my code to avoid calling the `innerHtml` member, a new bug crept up. I only converted html strings to DOM calls. No bugs are thrown in the chromium inspector. I am using mercurial, and the old version still works. I hunted around and:

```
alert(ctx.getTransform());
```

Returns `1,0,0,1,0,0` which is the identity transform. But my canvas is still scaled wrong. I don't call anything other than basic line and stroke members.

```
function buildColorTool() {
    var pick = document.createElement("DIV");

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.width = "200px";
    canvas.style.height = "200px";
    canvas.id = "wheelCanvas";
    pick.appendChild(canvas);
    document.getElementById("toolWindow").appendChild(pick);
}
```

Is broken, but:

```
 function buildColorTool() {
    let toolWindow = "<div class=\"toolDialogue\">";
    toolWindow += " <div id=\"colorPicker\">";
    toolWindow += "     <canvas id=\"wheelCanvas\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"></canvas>";
    toolWindow += " </div>";
    toolWindow += " </div>";

    document.getElementById("toolWindow").innerHTML = toolWindow;
 }
```

Works.
I used `hg diff -c 25 ./script.js > changes.txt`, is there a better set of mercurial arguments for posting to stack exchange?

Comment: Please post a [mre], or at least code we can use directly.

Comment: Use `canvas.width = 200;` (same for the height) instead of setting the style, otherwise you'll get a 300x150 canvas distorted to 200x200.

Comment: Thanks, that's my solution @Chris G. I'm going to try making the minimum reproducible now.

Comment: Duplicate: [Canvas width and height in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, is that you set the width and height of the element through it's style tag. This however [causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5) with canvas elements. Generally the height and width attributes are used for the actual sizing, and the CSS width/height is used for scaling.

**Solution**
Change

```
function newColorCanvas() {
   var pick = document.createElement("DIV");

   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.style.width = "200px";
   canvas.style.height = "200px";
   canvas.id = "wheelCanvas";
   canvas.innerText = "Canvas tag not supported";
   pick.appendChild(canvas);

   var select = document.createElement("P");
   select.id = "colorSelection";
   select.innerText = "HSL: 135, 75, 50";
   pick.appendChild(select);

   document.getElementById("toolWindow").appendChild(pick);

   paintCanvas(135,75,50);
   canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {updateCanvas();});
}
```

to

```
function newColorCanvas() {
   var pick = document.createElement("DIV");

   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width = 200;
   canvas.height = 200;
   canvas.id = "wheelCanvas";
   canvas.innerText = "Canvas tag not supported";
   pick.appendChild(canvas);

   var select = document.createElement("P");
   select.id = "colorSelection";
   select.innerText = "HSL: 135, 75, 50";
   pick.appendChild(select);

   document.getElementById("toolWindow").appendChild(pick);

   paintCanvas(135,75,50);
   canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {updateCanvas();});
}
```

Comment: If the question turns out to be a duplicate, please don't answer it but flag it as such. You can of course always post comments to give additional help to the OP.