# HTLMCanvasElement internal dimension changes result in wrong change its layout

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

as I read before

> The HTML  element actually has two dimensions, the intrinsic dimensions (using the .width and .height properties you're modifying in JS) and the displayed dimensions (controlled in CSS with their width & height properties)

So I have a canvas which style defined as follows:

```
    let st = canvas.style;
    st.width = "100%";
    st.height = "100%";
    st.outline = "none";
```

And the problem is that when I change it's internal dimensions very strange animation happening and its shrinking.
This animation is continues while the **left scrollbar** is visible on the page. Without visible scroll it does not happen.
The problems only appears when I set scale to 125% for my display in the system and.
Setting 100% in system and 125% in browser does not reproduce the problem.

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Canvas issue</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <style>
    html, body { background-color: #2b2b2b; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="module" charset="utf-8" src="example2.js"></script>

<button id="doit">Button1</button>
<button id="testme">Button2</button>

<div style="height: 50%" >
  <div style="height:100%; width: 50%; float:left">
    <div id="editor" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
    </div>
    <canvas
       width=100 height=100
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: none; cursor: text;"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the script:

```
    let container = document.getElementById("editor")

    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let st = canvas.style;
    st.width = "100%";
    st.height = "100%";
    st.outline = "none";

    const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        for (const entry of entries) {
            if (entry.target === canvas) {
                let size = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0];
                console.log("w = " + size.inlineSize + ", h = " + size.blockSize);
                canvas.width = size.inlineSize;
                canvas.height = size.blockSize;
                context.fillStyle = "green";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, size.inlineSize, size.blockSize);
            }
        }
    });
    observer.observe(canvas, {box: "device-pixel-content-box"});
    container.appendChild(canvas)
```

The question is about the canvas that was created dynamically from the JS script (not the canvas initially in the HTML body)

I am expecting that changes to the canvas.width and canvas.height should not trigger any page re-layout.

Comment: I will post hosted page shortly

Comment: Don't set canvas style with CSS or there'll be stretching artifacts. Use `canvas.width = 42` in JS and the `width="42"` HTML property exclusively. See [Canvas width and height in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5)

Comment: the sample in the link will not work when the window.devicePixelRatio != 1

Comment: Which sample are you referring to? There are many code samples in the linked thread.

Comment: My canvas has "width:100% height:100%" in CSS, and setting its drawing buffer resolution to actual pixels in javascript (modifying canvas.width and canvas.height) result in layout change again and again (and as result new different size in actual pixles). This loop is almost infinite regardless I have no changes in CSS and in layout.

Comment: here is the hosted reproducer
[link](https://kirillp.github.io/bugSizing.html)
It renders undesired animation when display settings set to 125% (windows settings) and the browser scale set to 100%, and the browser window and small.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with initial html page layout